Clarification needed in direct product and sum in the directed limit for the directed system of groups.
Background:
The following is taken from:  Graduate Course In Algebra, A - Volume 1
by: Ioannis Farmakis and Martin Moskowitz
Definition 1: Let $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of groups.  Then, the Cartesian product
$$\prod_{i\in I}G_i=\{f:I\to \cup_{i\in I}G_i:i\mapsto f(i)\in G_i\}$$
becomes a group under the following pointwise operation
$$f\cdot g \text{ such that }(f\cdot g)(i)=f(i)\cdot g(i)\in G_i$$
with unit element $1$ defined by $1(i)=1_{G_i}$ for each $i\in I$.
Definition 2: The direct sum of the family of the subgroup is defined as
$$\oplus_{i\in I}G_i=\{f\in \prod_{i\in I}G_i \text{ such that } f(i)\neq 1_{G_i},\text{ for all but finite number of }i\}$$
with the restricted operation.
Definition 3:  Let $(I, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set with the property that for any two elements $i,j$ there is some $k\in I$ such that $i\preceq k, j\preceq k$.
Definition 4:  A directed system of sets (groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.) indexed by $I$ is a collection of sets (rrespectively groups, rings, modules, topological spaces, etc.)  $X_i, i\in I)$, and maps (respectively homomorphisms, contiuous maps, etc.)  $f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$, defined whenever $i\preceq j$, satisfies the following compatibility conditions:

$f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}, i\preceq j \preceq k$, and
$f_{ii}=\mathrm{Id}_{X_i}$.

Definition 5:  A direct (or inductive) limit of the directed system of groups $G_i$, is defined by giving a group $G$ and a homomorphism
$$\phi_iG_i\to G$$
for any $i\in I$ such that

if $i<j$ then $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ \phi_{ij}$,
if $(G',\phi'_i)$ is another group and family of homormophisms with the same property then there exists a unique homomorphism
$$\phi: G\to G'$$
such that $\phi_i=\phi\circ \phi'_i$ for any $i\in I$.

The direct limit can be constructed as the quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$ as follows:  $$\varinjlim_{i\in I}G_i=\oplus_i G_i/\sim$$
where, $x_i\in G_i$ is equivalent to $x_j\in G_j$ if and only if
$$\phi_{ik}(x_i)=\phi_{jk}(x_j)$$
for some $k\in I,$ with the additional structure that the product of $x_i\in G_i, x_j\in G_j$ is defined as the product of their iimages in $G_k$.
Questions:
In continuation of this post, post.  I would like to ask
In Definition 5 2. where it says "The direct limit can be constructed as the quotient of the subgroup $\oplus_i G_i$ of $\prod_i G_i$...", here $\oplus_i G_i$ refers to the direct sum definition in Definition 2?  Also is the $\prod_i G_i$ referring to the cartesian product definition for family of groups in Definition 1?
Thank you in advance

Answer: of course they do. What else could they possibly refer to?

@ArturoMagidin like I said in my response to you in my other posts.  I am still new to these concepts.  I would feel better if I have assurances from people who already can work with these concepts in their sleep.


They introduce the notation. 2. They define what the notation means. 3. They use the notation. Then you ask "Does this notation mean what they said it means?" And I'm wondering what else you could possibly think the notation they both explicitly introduce and define could mean when they use it.


@ArturoMagidin I just want to make sure that the product and sum notations here are not one of those "depending on context" cases.

Again: they introduce it, they define it, they use it. If I say "I will use $r$ to denote the radius of a circle. The radius of a given circle is half the length of the largest line segment that fits entirely within the given circle. Let $C$ be a circle with $r=1$." Is there any doubt what $r$ refers to in those sentences? Even if it could mean something else somewhere else?
